# Mysql column with null values - what are the space requirements?

Tags: mysql, null, storage, requirements

I have a table with quite a lot entries.
I need an additional column with an integer value or null. 
The thing is that only very few rows will have that field populated.

So i wonder whether its better to create a seperate table where i link the entries in an 1:1 relation.

I know one integer entry takes 4 bytes in mysql/myisam. If I have the column set to allow null values, and only 100 of 100 000 rows have the field populated, will the rest still consume 4 bytes for every null value?

Or is mysql intelligent enough to set the value where it is populated and just regard everything as null, where nothing is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the ROW_FORMAT value you give when you create your table.

Before version 5.0.3, the default format is set to "REDUNDANT" : any fixed-length field will use the same space, even if it's value is NULL.

Starting with version 5.0.3, the value is set to "COMPACT" : NULL values will never use any space in your database.

You can do an ALTER TABLE to be sure to use the correct format :

```
ALTER TABLE ... ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

More details here :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-size.html

Comment: How could it be possible to use zero space to store null values? It has to cost something are it is not possible to remember the values.

Comment: @nate c ... well just store the data and every data that has no corresponding part is implicit null

Comment: There is nothing in that link that tells how nulls are stored. If I store 6 columns of ints where ther values are 33,44,66 Three columns are implicitly null. Which 3 columns are they? Thats zero storage. At the least you need a bitfield to tell which columns are there and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, once you declare a field as int, 4 bytes will be set aside for it. So, for 100,000 rows you are looking at ~ 400 KB of space.

If space is a constraint, then separate table will be better. On the other hand, if performance is a criteria, then you'll have to take into account how many times that field is queried and whether it is checked for existence or non-existence. In either case, you'll need a join. If you want to check whether the field is set you can use inner join, which will be slower than single table query. If you want to check for non-existence, you'll need left/right outer join which will be slower than inner join.

Answer (score 0):

It will use bitfields to store nulls so it may need less than one byte. But, even if it did - who cares, unless you are using 3.5" floppies to store your backend in ;-)

[NULL in MySQL (Performance & Storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage)