# MySQL NULL Row Storage Size

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a column not defined as `NOT NULL`, meaning that particular column may be null. If I insert a row with a null entry for that field, how many bytes does it take to store that entry?

In more general terms, if a table has lots of NULL entries in it, is it wasting storage space?

Comment: I'm probably not understanding.  Are you saying it has a NOT NULL constraint?  If you have a column with a NOT NULL constraint, then it shouldn't allow you to insert a new row with a null for that field.

Comment: I edited the question. That column may contain a null entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link  answering your question.
[Null in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage)

Comment: please add the response in text, not only the link