# Optional fields on very large db

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on the redesign of a mysql bdd. 
This database is actually a huge table of 200 fields, several million lines, almost no index... In short, disastrous performances and huge ram consumption!

I first managed to reduce the number of fields by setting up 1:n relationships.

I have a question on a specific point: 
A number of fields on this database are optional and rarely filled in. (sometimes almost never) 
What is the best thing to do in this case?

- leave the field in the table even if it is very often of null value
- set up a n:n relationship knowing that these relationships, if they exist, will only return one line
- ...or another solution I haven't thought of

Thank you in advance for your wise advice;) 
Dimitri

Comment: `NULL` values may take up less or no space, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312215/mysql-how-much-space-does-a-null-field-use).  Other than this, normalizing your table, as you are already doing, is probably the best improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I don't really care about disk space. The main purpose of that refactoring is to improve performances especially when doing Select queries.

Comment: Then look into normalization and setting up appropriate indices.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

- First of all, make sure to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your db. At least to [3rd Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). This will probably reduce some of your original columns and split them over several tables.
- Once that is done, in case you still have lots of 'optional and rarely filled' columns in some of your tables, consider how to proceed depending on your needs: What is most important to you? Disk space or Performance?

Take a look at [MySQL Optimazing Data Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-size.html) for extra tips/improvements for the re-design of your database ...depending on your needs.

Regarding 'set up a n:n relationship...' (I figure you meant 1:1 relationship) can be an interesting option in some cases:

*In some circumstances, it can be beneficial to split into two a table that is scanned very often. This is especially true if it is a dynamic-format table and it is possible to use a smaller static format table that can be used to find the relevant rows when scanning the table* (extracted from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-size.html))

Comment: Many thanks ! The most important by far is performance improvement.
I would act on a case-by-case basis for these optionnal columns.

Comment: Then work hard on normalization, and then in defining right indexes. And don't worry if some 'optional and rarely filled' columns remains.