# Is it bad to have a column empty as NULL often in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, dbnull

Is it bad to have a column empty as `NULL` **often** in a table?

`comment` table

```
comment_id     member_id    user_id
1              1            NULL
2              1            NULL
3              1            NULL
4              1            NULL
5              1            NULL
6              1            NULL
7              NULL         1
8              NULL         1
9              NULL         1
10             1            NULL
```

Comment: What is the difference of a member and a user?

Comment: `user` is an admin. `member` is a public user in my context...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage

Comment: @lauthiamkok when you define the public user (member) id?

Comment: I don't know your code or mysql, but think you end up inflating your database with data repeated. If I comment two times, I will end with two ids, or not?

Comment: `If I comment two times, I will end with two ids, or not?` yes - is it bad?? but it is like you just commented twice in this thread...

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not inherently bad. A `NULL` entry is a tool, and you may use that tool as you like.

Now, in the case you posted, you might consider having non-overlapping user and member IDs and using one column to store either, but that's your decision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Borealid! :-)

Comment: `Now, in the case you posted, you might consider having non-overlapping user and member IDs and using one column to store either, but that's your decision.` sorry I dont quite get this - do you mean one table for users and another table for members?

Comment: @lauthiamkok I meant that, if someone is either a "member" or a "user", you could assign a different type of ID to each one (so you could distinguish which type they were from the ID). Then you wouldn't need two columns. But, like I said, up to you.

Comment: `a different type of ID` - like `member-1` for a member and `user-2` for an user?

Comment: @lauthiamkok That would work, yes. The idea is just to let you do a join without having to worry about colliding IDs, were you to have separate tables for each of the user types.

Comment: oh then what should I name the column that colliding two columns (like the ones I have - user_id and member_id) together then?

Comment: Just noticing: `'member-1'` and `'user-2'` is not the best. Perhaps two columns `'M', 1` and `'U',2` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not causing much of a performance issue. It looks like you have some sort of distinction between members and users in your table. Assuming nobody can be a member AND a user, you could have one column for member/user id but then you would need another column to identify whether they were a user or a member. That would actually require MORE storage than the solution you have now so I think you're fine.

Comment: It would actually require the same storage or less. Instead of two ids (lets say 4+4=8 bytes), you could have one id and the distinction column (that's 4+1=5 bytes).

Comment: NULL values should take 0 bytes though, no? I do not think MySQL will still allocate 4 bytes if the values are null, I could be mistaken though

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not 'bad' although some die-hard Normalization fanatics will insist that allowing `null`s violates relational database laws.

If you have a table with a lot of them, you might want to take a look and see if the design is appropriate but you can't say it's bad in every case without more context.

Comment: It doesn't matter if we insist or not. It does violate relational theory. It's not like the end of world but it has several drawbacks.