# Join table dynamically MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am new in MySQL. I am not sure that i am right thing. Need help.

I have a table `survey` which have the following column:

`id, source_type, source_id, survey_date_time`.

Other two tables are:

`education` which have `id, col1, col2, col3` columns.

`games` which have `id, col4, col5, col6` columns.

Data in `survey` table:

```
id       source_type    source_id    survey_date_time
--------------------------------------------------------
100      education         1         2013-07-25 00:00:00
101      games             1         2013-07-25 00:00:00
102      games             2         2013-07-26 00:00:00
103      education         2         2013-07-26 00:00:00
```

Data in `education` table

```
id    col1          col2          col3      
--------------------------------------------
1     col1_data1    col2_data1    col3_data1
2     col1_data2    col2_data2    col3_data2
```

Data in `games` table

```
id    col4          col5          col6      
--------------------------------------------
1     col4_data1    col5_data1    col6_data1
2     col4_data2    col5_data2    col6_data2
```

I want to read data dynamically like:

`select * from survey left join {survey.sorce_type} on {survey.sorce_type}.id=survey.source_id where survey.id={given_id}`

You can find the the schema [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee71c)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**
select statement will be `survey.*, {survey.sorce_type}.*` instead of `*`

Thanks

Comment: Technically, you need to use Dynamic SQL, which means MySQL's Prepared Statement syntax

Answer (score 7):

This should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
  FROM survey s
    LEFT JOIN eduction e ON s.source_type = 'education' AND e.id = s.source_id
    LEFT JOIN games g ON s.source_type = 'games' AND g.id = s.source_id
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee71c/8).

Essentially, this joins the appropriate table based on the `source_type`.  So when it is `education` it joins to the `eduction` table (you may have a spelling mistake there) and when it is `games` it joins to the `games` table.

Comment: currently i have two tables. education, games. but in future there will be more table. so i cann't add join for each table.

Comment: You would have to redesign the table structure... e.g.  survey_data: survey_type_id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6.  survey_type: id, type_name.  survey: id, survey_type_id, survey_data_id, date_created.

Comment: @AEQ Could you explain that approach you are suggesting some more?

Comment: It has been awhile since I had a look at this but I think this is what I was thinking of @antoniovassell: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76889/3

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to create a procedure with prepared statements.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE `JoinWithSurvey`(param_leftTable VARCHAR(50), param_id VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
SET @QUERY1 = concat('select survey.*,',param_leftTable,'.* from survey left join ',param_leftTable,' on  ',param_leftTable,'.id=survey.source_id where survey.id = ', param_id ,';');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY1;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END |
```

Then call that sp

```
call JoinWithSurvey('eduction','100');

ID  SOURCE_TYPE SOURCE_ID   SURVEY_DATE_TIME    COL1    COL2    COL3
100 education   1   July, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 col1_data1  col2_data1  col3_data1

call JoinWithSurvey('games','102');

ID  SOURCE_TYPE SOURCE_ID   SURVEY_DATE_TIME    COL4    COL5    COL6
102 games   2   July, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000 col4_data2  col5_data2  col6_data2
102 education   2   July, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000 col4_data2  col5_data2  col6_data2
```

I passed id as a varchar here.. You can use as integer type as well.. :)

Have a try

***[Working fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37f5f/2)***

Comment: Thanks. But is there any solution where i don't have to pass the table name(which is `source_type`)? I just want to pass the `survey` table `id`. The table will be dynamically join with the `survey` from the `source_type`.

Comment: How the system will know that you need to join these all tables unless you told the system to join. ?. An alternative solution is already pointed by Martin Parkin, where you need to tell all the tables to go and join. Hope you got my point.

Comment: The `source_type` column is the table name. If i had the id then i can find the table form the `source_type` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could redesign the table structure which would then allow you to add more survey types, if the columns are the same, then you can reuse columns but if not, null data uses very little space (Ref: [NULL in MySQL (Performance & Storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage))

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76889/3