# Add column to table which will be empty for most rows

Tags: mysql

I have an existing table in our database which is already populated. I now have additional data I want to store in this table but this data will need to store one additional field (probably a VARCHAR(40) ). Last thing I want is to somehow allocate this space for all the existing entries that won't use it. Is MySQL somehow 'smart' enough not to increase the size of the table significantly if this field is set to NULL or would I perhaps be better off creating a new table for data that includes this extra data field?

Comment: varchar is smart enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which storage engine you are using.InnoDB storage engine (which is default) improves the performance if you have most of the value in your column as `NULL`.

Because In **InnoDB**, each column has a **"field start offset"** in the row header, which is one or two bytes per column. The high bit in that field start offset is on if the column is NULL. In that case, the column doesn't need to be stored at all. So if you have a lot of NULL's your storage should be significantly reduced.

Reference:
[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230923/31866810)
[Example for null value performance efficiency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-field-contents.html)

Note: If you want to implement the same in MS SQL you may consider `SPARSE`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had searched SO but not spotted that one.