# What is the syntax for a where clause for many columns from different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm creating database for a place which have meeting rooms for reserve & sell books. The schema is genericized to allow reuse of tables for multiple data sets.

[image: Database Diagram]

The diagram is slightly incorrect; there are two `selector` tables which actually have distinct names. The `selector` table in the top right is actually called `option_selector` and the bottom left is `values_selector`. I fill the `resource_type` table with `1, room`; `2, book` then `resource_option` with `1, Name`; `2, size`; `3,Author`; `4,Publish Year` and fill the `option_selector` table with the rows.

- `1, 1, 1` for mapping room to name
- `2, 1, 2` for mapping room to size
- `3, 2, 1` for mapping book to name
- `4, 2, 3` for mapping book to author
- `5, 2, 4` for mapping book to Publish Year

I also fill the `option_selector` and `option_value` tables with some rows. Then I run this query

```
SELECT r.id as 'book ID', v.value as 'Name'
FROM resources r
  JOIN value_selector s ON r.id = s.resource_id
JOIN resourse_option_value v ON s.value_id = v.id
WHERE v.option_selector_id = 3
ORDER BY r.id
```

The result

```
book ID    Name
5          Journey to the center of the Earth
6          Oliver Travels
7          C How To Program
8          Java How To Program
```

And that's the right output.

The problem is I want add more data columns to be selectable with the book records, for example 'Author' & 'Publish Year' to make this output table look like

```
book ID    Name    Author     Publish Year
```

I tried this

```
SELECT r.id as 'book ID', v.value as 'Name', v2.value as 'Author', v3.value as 'Year'
FROM resourses r
  JOIN value_selector s ON r.id = s.resourse_id
  JOIN resourse_option_value v ON s.value_id = v.id
  JOIN resourse_option_value v2 ON s.value_id = v2.id
  JOIN resourse_option_value v3 ON s.value_id = v3.id
WHERE
  v.option_selector_id = 3 AND
  v2.option_selector_id = 4 AND
  v3.option_selector_id = 5
ORDER BY r.id
```

This gives an empty result

Database sql : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/302671/3

Comment: Just add those column names to the select list?

Comment: cannot because  they have the same table name
i can't type 
SELECT r.id as 'book ID', v.value as 'Name', v.value as 'Author' ,v.value as 'Publish Year' they all will give the same resault because option_selector_id = 3 @jarlh

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice... Don't store data like that! You see, it's already causing you problems!

Comment: I must use the EAV @jarlh

Comment: Do another JOIN with the same table. (Call it v2 this time.)

Comment: is there any way to use WHERE for each v.values

Comment: WHERE v.value = x AND v2.value = y

Comment: in your diagram you have 2 tables with the same name `selector` with different set of columns. How is it possible?

Comment: i called one option_selector & the other one value_selector @Alex

Comment: your link is not working. create sqlfifddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: ... and I think you've just demonstrated one of the reasons why this is a bad way t store data. Why not just have two tables: Room and Book? Then put the data about the room in Room and the data about a boo in Book. Make separate fields for each fact: author, title, publisher,whatever. I think 90% of your problems will go away.

Comment: My Doc says this way prevent  Data repetition & nulls @Jay

Comment: There are much better ways to prevent data repetition. Namely, having separate tables for the things that might repeat. Like if you care that two books might have the same author, then create an author table and put a foreign key from Book to Author. Avoid nulls? Who cares? They cost very little. I don't know where you're getting this advice but in my humble opinion it's terrible advice. As you can see from this example, it's turning a trivially simple database into something complex and confusing. Imagine trying to do this if you had not just Rooms and Books but also, say, ...

Comment: ... pubishers and conference attendees and transactions for book purchases and scheduling of the rooms and a dozen other things. It would be a nightmare.

Comment: I corrected some spelling and capitalization and laid out the data in a more understandable format. Hopefully you agree that it's more readable. I'm pretty sure you had the resource IDs for book and room switched - they were different in the SQL fiddle - so I switched them. The schema in the fiddle also looks more complicated, with the `resourece_option_value`  being a blend of two tables in the diagram image you included. Welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database structure is still not clear to me.

But just to give you an idea where to start you can try this one:

```
SELECT 
  r.id as 'book ID', 
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 3,v.value, null)) as 'Name',
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 4,v.value, null)) as 'Author',
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 5,v.value, null)) as 'Publish year'
FROM resourses r
JOIN value_selector s
ON r.id = s.resourse_id
JOIN resourse_option_value v
ON s.value_id = v.id
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY r.id
```

I feel that this query will not bring you expected result since it is value depended query and I have no idea what are correct values are. So if you provide more samples of your data we can figure out what is correct query in your case. Please provide samples for all tables and/or sqlfiddle would be perfect.

**EDIT 1** So if you need only books, just add `WHERE r.type_id = 2`clause:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/302671/12

```
SELECT 
  r.id as 'book ID', 
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 3,v.value, null)) as 'Name',
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 4,v.value, null)) as 'Author',
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 5,v.value, null)) as 'Publish year'
FROM resourses r
JOIN value_selector s
ON r.id = s.resourse_id
JOIN resourse_option_value v
ON s.value_id = v.id
WHERE r.type_id = 2
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY r.id
```

**EDIT 2** To get books in specific year you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/302671/15

```
SELECT 
  r.id as 'book ID', 
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 3,v.value, null)) as 'Name',
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 4,v.value, null)) as 'Author',
  MAX(IF(v.option_selector_id = 5,v.value, null)) as 'Publish year'
FROM resourses r
JOIN value_selector s
ON r.id = s.resourse_id
JOIN resourse_option_value v
ON s.value_id = v.id
WHERE r.type_id = 2
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING `Publish year`=2014
ORDER BY r.id
```

Comment: the query works good but gives NULL for book id 1,2,3,4 which is another resource  i'll provide my sql Database now

Comment: I Created the sql on sqlfiddle.com please help @Alex

Comment: Don't understand what is your problem is. check update.

Comment: How To get the books only publish in specific year like 2014 @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Well, Alex's answer shows that the schema is workable. It's still pretty crazy, in my opinion. In particular, needing the `MAX` and `HAVING` clauses in what should be simple lookup statements are very concerning for the scalability. For comparison, consider the schema with separate tables as proposed by Jay instead.

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `bookId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `author` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `publishYear` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookId`));

INSERT INTO `book` (`title`, `author`, `publishDate`) VALUES
("Journey to the center of the Earth", "Johny", 2013),
("Oliver Travels", "Ahmed Ali", 2015);

CREATE TABLE `room` (
  `roomId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`roomId`));

INSERT INTO `room` (`name`) VALUES
  ("Library"), ("Study"), ("Hall"), ("Dining Room"), ("Kitchen"), ("Conservatory"), ("Billiard Room"), ("Lounge"), ("Ballroom");
```

And you're done. No nulls (which aren't a big problem in MySQL anyways, and actually [reduce storage requirements on the InnoDB engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage)), no foreign keys, half the SQL to pull it off. You can easily tell what any data record is by its table name and ID without having to check three different tables for column names, option names and values.

Need the books?

```
SELECT `bookId`, `title`, `author`, `publishYear` FROM `book`;
```

From a certain year? (Might want to add an index on the publish year.)

```
SELECT `bookId`, `title`, `author`, `publishYear` FROM `book`
WHERE `publishYear` = 2013;
```

Need to allow books to have multiple authors?

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `authorId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45),
  `bookId` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`authorId`));

ALTER TABLE `book` DROP COLUMN `author`;

SELECT `b`.`bookId`, `title`, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as authors, `publishYear`
FROM `book` b
LEFT JOIN `author` a ON `a`.`bookId` = `b`.`bookId`
GROUP BY `b`.`bookId`;
```

Add foreign keys if you're so inclined.