# If I have a VARCHAR(32) with no data inside it, does it take any space?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database and I'd like to know if I have a VARCHAR(32) with no data inside it, does it take any space, like some `kb`?

The reason I'm asking it is because I store a hash of 32 chars to check something but after a while I'll not use it anymore, so if it takes some of DB space, I might make this field null or empty.

If so, should I make this field null or empty to save some space?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, I doubt you'll win any significant space this way.

Comment: please  note. MySQL release never allocated space also if you delete row. the only way to free it is to save the table, truncate it and fill it again

Comment: If you look [at the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) it is all explain very nicely as long as you can be botherd to read it.

Comment: @BerndBuffen, I guess you are right, it seems that if I change the field from 32 chars to 0 it doesn't save any space, but do you have any references to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` values occupy space for the `NULL` flag.  In addition, any fixed component of the data type is also stored.  For a `VARCHAR()` that is the length component, which is either 1 or 2 bytes.

The storage requirement for `VARCHAR()` is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html).  For `VARCHAR(32)` the length is stored as a single byte.

Arrgh.  I forgot that in MySQL, this depends on the storage engine.  The above is true for MyISAM.  It is different for InnoDB.  Here is a [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage) answer.