# Optimize MySql 5.7 table without downtime

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I have a table in MySql 5.7 server. We store around 1M rows every day. After each row insertion, we do some processing on that row after that we delete that row.

Table disk space is rapidly increasing because of this huge number of write operations. So I want to do OPTIMIZE the Table.

So if I apply OPTIMIZE Table command on production table does it give any downtime.

What is the best way to do OPTIMIZE table?

**MySql Server details**

Server version: **5.7**

Engine: **InnoDB**

Hosting: **Google Cloud Sql**

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your use case. Why are you deleting the rows? Are you not using MySQL for transactional data? In that case, it shouldn't be deleted. Are you using MySQL as OLAP? That might not be a good idea altogether. Please elaborate your business requirement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, OPTIMIZE TABLE will perform the work in place as of MySQL 5.6.17 or later.  We find this note in the documentation on which operations support online DDL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html

You can experiment to test this (I did after your comment):

1. Create a table and fill it with a few hundred thousand rows of random data.
2. Run OPTIMIZE TABLE, because a table of that size will take 20-30 seconds or more.
3. While that is running, open a second window and try SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE against the table. You will find it does not block DML.

If you do have an ALTER TABLE that cannot work as online DDL, there's a good free tool [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) that help to avoid locking behavior even for table-restructure operations. This tool does NOT lock the table, but it creates triggers so any changes are captured and applied to the new copy table while it's in progress of copying all the rows.

Comment: but MySQL 5.7 supports online DDL so I thought that we won't get any downtime because they use ALGORITHM=INPLACE. am I wrong?

Comment: @Rams, you're right. I have edited my answer. Apologies for my inaccurate answer.